# Unity gone in 14.04, unable to bring it back

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, 16.04, desktop-environments

I tried a few discussions before deciding it would be wise to ask here. I don't know when I lost Unity desktop. I had to bank on Gnome and Cinnamon I had alongside Unity. I was using one of these alternatives while I noticed that Unity desktop is no longer an option during log in, and is missing. Most guides online say use

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But I am having dependency issues here.

Another thing is I want to upgrade to 16.04. I thought of waiting for the point release, but would go ahead anyway now. But for that, when I use

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

I get a partial upgrade notice and it fails eventually. When I agree with *Partial Upgrade* option, Ubuntu says `impossible to install ubuntu-desktop` or something similar. The *Partial Upgrade* throws an error and take back to the *Partial Upgrade* option. Thus, I am not able to try 16.04 as well. Please help..

```
 $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some
 packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
 an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
 that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
 out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
 situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  ubuntu-desktop :
 Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed  
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` after it fails?

Comment: sudo apt-get install unity, if it doesn't work, try to install the following packages manually in this order: unity-settings-daemon, unity-control-center, ubuntu-desktop and then try again unity... what hapens?